# WordPress ajax call with add_filter

Tags: ajax, wordpress, add-filter

I have a WordPress function that works exactly how I want. The function below changes the email recipient in Contact Form 7 to abc@aol.com.

Now I need to use AJAX to update the email recipient to a dynamic value.

```
function wpcf7_dynamic_email_field($args) {
  if(!empty($args['recipient'])) {
    $args['recipient'] = str_replace('%admin%', 'abc@aol.com', $args['recipient']);
    return $args;
  }
  return false;
}
add_filter('wpcf7_mail_components', 'wpcf7_dynamic_email_field');
```

Here's my AJAX call. I do not know how to tell the call to initiate the `wpcf7_dynamic_email_field()` function. Can that be done?

```
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl, // or example_ajax_obj.ajaxurl if using on frontend
  data: {
    'action': 'update_team_page_contact_form',
    'emailAddress' : emailAddress
  },
  success:function(data) {
    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(errorThrown){
    console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Comment: you want to call your own function or use contact form?

Comment: @Jinesh I want to use my wpcf7_dynamic_email_field() function that updates the contact form.  I need to run wpcf7_dynamic_email_field() asynchronously.